# Write to file meta data Windows Store apps

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, metadata

I have following code:

```
var props = App.CurrentFile.Properties.GetDocumentPropertiesAsync();
        props.GetResults().Comment = "Comments goes here";
        await props.GetResults().SavePropertiesAsync();
```

The CurrentFile is of type StorageFile. When I try to save updated Comment value using SavePropertiesAsync(), it fails with following COM exception.

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

I am following very basic example at this blog:

http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2011/10/17/winrt-wps-part1-storing-retrieving-metadata/

Any idea?

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: Make sure you await the GetDocumentPropertiesAsync call.

Answer (score 2):

File format must support meta data. For example XML file cannot have any properties, but JPEG file can.